# Return JsonObject in spring restful webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, json

I am using spring framework. I have a webservice in Wepsphere server like that

```
@RequestMapping (value="/services/SayHello2Me" , method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject SayHello2Me(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String input = (String) request.getParameter("name");
    String output = "hello " + input + " :)";
    JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    outputJsonObj.put("output", output);
        return outputJsonObj;
      }
```

When I call it form Chrome like http://myserver/services/sayHello2Me?name='baris', it returns me that error :

> Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404

If I change annotions in my webservice like that

```
@RequestMapping (value="/services/SayHello2Me")
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject SayHello2Me(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    String input = (String) request.getParameter("name");
    String output = "hello " + input + " :)";
    JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    outputJsonObj.put("output", output);

    return outputJsonObj;
  }
```

then when I call it form Chrome like http://myserver/services/sayHello2Me?name='baris', it returns me that error :

> Error 406: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 406

There is a jsonobject problem because if I return String insted of jsonobject in same webservice it returns me successfully.

How can I return Jsonobject in spring restful webservice?

Comment: The mappings does not match. When you change it to be the same in both places is it ok?

Comment: All mappings do match. Just I made mistake while writing here. I updated my question.

Comment: Why don't you just return a POJO? Jackson handles the rest and generates a JSON string.

Comment: Imho in that case your request does not go to http://myserver/services/sayHello2Me but http://myserver/services/sayHello2Me/{name}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 406-Not Acceptable Response

you should use `return outputJsonObj.toString();` try below as

```
@RequestMapping (value="/services/SayHello2Me")
@ResponseBody
public String SayHello2Me(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

String input = (String) request.getParameter("name");
String output = "hello " + input + " :)";
JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
outputJsonObj.put("output", output);

return outputJsonObj.toString();
}
```

Comment: If I do that 
I get this warning in compiler:Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to JSONObject

Comment: which JSON library are you using ??

Comment: import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject; @Pravin

Comment: Please check edit change return type from josnobject to string

Comment: @Pravin I am a bit late to the party but am running into something similar. The toString works but does this not defeat the purpose of having a JSON object? Will JavaScript be able to interpret this as an array and parse it on the front end?

Comment: yes, you need to do `JSON.parse(response)` in your JS file

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackson:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/services/SayHello2Me" , method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
```

Comment: I made that but nothing is changed